# (Sphero) robot sdk not working for 64 bit architecture and ios 8.2 in ios

Tags: ios

I've tried to get this project to build with no success. No code or project modifications just downloaded and tried to build. ios8.2 XCode 6.1.1 
https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/Beta

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKConvenienceRobot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HelloWorldViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRobotDiscoveryAgent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HelloWorldViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Try running the app stright after openning with Xcode. Don't try to remove the warnings. The Sphero SDK needs some configuration for compiling and last versions of Xcode warns it as deprecated or something like that...

Comment: Thanks,it worked,it should be noted that the app needs to run on a connected iOS device for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue, it happens when we are running our code on simulator it needs ios device then all is well.